# Flextable: make the signif stars bold and remove the space between stars and the coefficient

Tags: r, flextable

I'm testing `flextable`, a package for R by David Gohel, for the publication workflow and I was wondering about how to format substrings in the cells of the regression tables. In particular, I aim to replicate Stata's outreg2 with significance stars in bold and right next to the coefficient.

Here is the reprex:

```
library(huxtable)
library(flextable)
lm(formula=mpg~cyl+hp, mtcars) %>% huxreg() %>% as_flextable()
```

[image]

Now I am trying to make the significance stars in bold and right next to the coefficient without the space in between.

If anyone could chime in, it would be great! I'm looking at `ftExtra` but I see no way how to approach this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flextable, you can do it quite easily by adding a signif. column after the p-values column and use 0 padding.

The following code demo how to do it from scratch:

```
x <- lm(formula=mpg~cyl+hp, mtcars)

library(flextable)
library(broom)
library(magrittr)

pvalue_format <- function(x){
  z <- cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, Inf), labels = c("***", "**", "*", ".", ""))
  as.character(z)
}

tidy(x) %>% 
  flextable(
    col_keys = c("term", "estimate", "std.error", "statistic", "p.value", "signif")) %>% 
  colformat_double(digits = 4) %>% 
  mk_par(j = "signif", value = as_paragraph(pvalue_format(p.value)) ) %>% 
  set_header_labels(term = "", estimate = "Estimate",
                    std.error = "Standard Error", statistic = "t value",
                    p.value = "Pr(>|t|)", signif = "" ) %>% 
  align(j = "signif", align = "left") %>% 
  padding(padding.right = 0, j = "p.value", part  = "all") %>% 
  bold(j = "signif", bold = TRUE) %>% 
  padding(padding.left = 0, j = "signif", part  = "all") %>% 
  autofit()
```

[image]

You can also use the `flextable::as_flextable` method and adapt the result to your needs:

```
as_flextable(x) %>% 
  delete_part(part = "footer") %>% 
  padding(padding.right = 0, j = "p.value", part  = "all") %>% 
  padding(padding.left = 0, j = "signif", part  = "all") %>% 
  color(i = ~ p.value > .05, j = "p.value", color = "gray") %>% 
  theme_vanilla()
```

[image]

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you. I'm a bit confused here though: none of these make the significance stars in **bold**? Just the stars, not the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possibility:

```r
lm(formula=mpg~cyl+hp, mtcars) |> 
      huxreg(
        stars = c(
          '__*__' = 0.05,  
          '__**__' = 0.01
        )
      ) |> 
      set_markdown(2:6, 2, TRUE) |>
      as_flextable()
```

This uses markdown to bold the stars.

You may get errors from flextable. If so, you could save as HTML or RTF and convert to Word. (And report the bug.)

Comment: Thank you for the code! Would it be possible to apply markdown automatically to columns with significance stars, no matter if there is 1 or more such column?
I'm trying the following code but it gives an error (Error in rep(list(flatten_branch), n) : invalid 'times' argument) :

lm(formula=mpg~cyl+hp, mtcars) %>% huxreg(number_format =3, note=NULL, stars = c(
  '__*__' = 0.1,  
  '__**__' = 0.05,
  '__***__' = 0.01
)) %>%set_number_format(3) %>%
  huxtable::set_markdown(.,everywhere ,tidyselect::matches("*"), TRUE) %>% 
  huxtable::as_flextable()

Comment: Yes, you could. The simplest way is to know the table dimensions and work out where there "should be" significance stars from that. You probably want `grepl` to search content, not `matches` which is for column names.